# Es necesario usar la palabra var, let o const

Tags: javascript

Lo digo porque en el segundo ejemplo no se usa la palabra *var* sin embargo funciona mostrando el texto almacenado, entonces ¿cuándo es necesario usar *var* *let* o *const*?

```js
var a = "Hola";
e = "hola";

alert(a);
alert(e);
```

Comment: Digamos que... en javascript "usar algo es mejor que usar nada", si bien puedes definir variables sin necesidad de declararlas ya sea como var, let o const, normalmente no es adecuado, puesto que crea una variable global, y pues la cosa con las variables globales es que sin querer puedes cambiar su contenido sin darte cuenta y otros muchos problemas, de hecho actualmente no deberia usarse var, deberia comenzar a usar let, puesto que let tiene un ambito limitado por bloques, el cual no contaminara el scope global.

Comment: O tambien recomendaria incluso mas const siempre que puedas usarlo y el proposito de esa variable sea de solo lectura.